# Two types of postback events

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, gridview, postback

1) I found two articles, each categorizing a bit differently the two types of postback events:

> One resource says the two types of postback events are **Changed** event ( where controls implement IPostbackDataHandler ), which fires when data is changed between postbacks, and then are **Raised** events ( where controls implement IPostbackEventHandler ), which are raised by server controls for whatever reason the control sees fit
>
> Other article says the two types are **Immediate response** events and **Change** events. According to this article, Immediate response events are ones that actually trigger a postback

a) Which categorization is correct?

b) If second article was correct, then if TextBox control had AutoPostBack=”true”, shouldn’t then TextChanged  also be considered Immediate response event?

2) When page is submitted back to the server due to some user action,  *then at Event handling stage*, ASP.NET raises events of all controls that got their data changed since the last postback. The event that actually triggered a postback ( such as Click event ) is raised last

a) But what if user selecting a row in GridView caused a postback? When GridView causes a postback due to Row selection, then unlike simpler controls ( like TextBox or Button ), that postback causes GridView to fire not one, but several server-side events during Event handling stage ( SelectedIndexChaning and SelectedIndexChanged).

Which of these GridView’s events is considered by ASP.NET to be the one that caused a postback?

thank you

Comment: Which articles are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

The SelectedIndexChanged event (on a listbox) and the TextChanged event (on a Textbox) will fire on a postback even if the Autopostback property is false.

Try putting this on a form:

```
   <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="test" 
        onselectedindexchanged="test_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem >number1</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem >number2</asp:ListItem>     
</asp:ListBox>

<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="text" ontextchanged="text_TextChanged" />
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Click Me" />
```

and this in the code behind:

```
 protected void test_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("SelectedIndexChanged");
    }

    protected void text_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("TextChanged");
    }
```

Then run it, change the selected item, type some text, and hit the button - both events fire. You can see the sequence of events using Reflector. For the Textbox, the RaisePostDataChangedEvent method is:

```
 protected virtual void RaisePostDataChangedEvent()
{
    if (this.AutoPostBack && !this.Page.IsPostBackEventControlRegistered)
    {
        this.Page.AutoPostBackControl = this;
        if (this.CausesValidation)
        {
            this.Page.Validate(this.ValidationGroup);
        }
    }
    this.OnTextChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SelectedIndexChanging is called first and is typically where I make any sort of updates. SelectedIndexChanged happens AFTER SelectedIndexChanging, so technically the page sees the SelectedIndexChanging as the event that caused the postback. Remember that a postback also calls the entire lifecycle of the page from Init to Page_Load to your event.

the autopostback property just lets the site know to do a postback after whatever change occurs, be it textchanged, selectedindexchanged, checkedchanged, etc. if the autopostback property is not set to true, these events will not occur.

Comment: As far as I know, even if autopostback property is set to false, TextChanged, SelectedIndexChanged etc events will happen non the less, once page is posted back

Comment: no, the event will not fire because the page is not posting back as a result of the control calling for a postback. try it: create a textbox, define an "ontextchanged" event with some code, but don't set your autopostback property to true. your ontextchanged code will never run. believe me, i run into this error far too frequently in my own code ;)

Answer (score 0):

First, it sounds to me like both categorizations are compatible, just a different way of putting it.  I suppose you could say that Raised events are equivalent to Immediate Response events, which are only possible in controls that implement IPostbackEventHandler.

So regarding 1b, when AutoPostBack = true, I believe it just sets up a javascript onchange event to make a postback call.  Once the postback fires, the page detects that the textbox has changed and runs the changed event. Thus this still isn't a Raised Event.  (I could be wrong, but that's my understanding.)

A Raise Event would be one triggered in a control's RaisePostBack method (required by IPostBackEventHandler)--which happens after the page load cycle and triggering each change event.

Under the hood, a postback can occur in one of two ways: by submitting the form (asp:button with submit behavior) or by a javascript _doPostBack call (occurs in controls where AutoPostBack=true or when you make the call directly using Page.ClientScript).